# ORACLE-SQL: stored procedure using array as parameter for select

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have to use an array into my stored procedure.
So I created a type variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE integer_array is table of number;
```

Then I tried to write my stored procedure, but I can't to compile it:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE SP_TEST(
      i_id_profiles in integer_array, 
      o_clients OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
   )
AS
BEGIN
open o_clients for 
    FOR i IN 1..i_id_profiles.count LOOP
      select a.id_client from b_client a, i_client_profile b where a.id_client = b.id_client 
      and b.id_profile = i_id_profiles(i);
    END LOOP;
END SP_TEST;
```

Can you help me? I want to get a SYS_REFCURSOR of my select.

thanks

The error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the
>   following:     ( - + case mod new not null select with     
>    continue avg count current exists max min    prior
>   sql stddev sum variance execute forall merge time    timestamp
>   interval date          pipe
>
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of
>   the following:     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding
>   static    member constructor map

Comment: WHats the compilation error?

Comment: I add now the compilation errors, but in my opinion the stored procedure is totaly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You open a ref cursor for a query(static or dynamic), you cannot open a ref cursor for a `for loop` construct or any kind of loop construct. It simply semantically incorrect.
Moreover, in this situation, there is no need of a loop of any kind at all. As you've created the `integer_array` as sql type(schema object) you can use `table` operator to simply select from the instance of that type(represent it as a table). So your procedure might look like this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_TEST(
      i_id_profiles in integer_array, 
      o_clients OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
   )
AS
BEGIN
  open o_clients for 
      select a.id_client 
         from b_client a 
         join i_client_profile b 
           on (a.id_client = b.id_client)
         join table(i_id_profiles)  s
           on b.id_profile = s.column_value;
END SP_TEST;
```